# Can I create LinkButtons that wrap like textfields?

Tags: apache-flex

I basically want to make things easier by just looping LinkButtons instead of making textfields because the linkbuttons have the rollovers already programmed.

But I have a lot of text and it just keeps going. I want it to wrap like I can do with textfields.

Thanks

```
package {
 import mx.controls.LinkButton;
 import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;

 public class multiLineLinkButton extends LinkButton {
      override protected function createChildren():void {
           super.createChildren();
           if (textField){
                textField.wordWrap = true;
                textField.multiline = true;

           }
      }

      override public function measureText(s:String):TextLineMetrics {
           textField.text = s;
           var lineMetrics:TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
           lineMetrics.width = 700;
           lineMetrics.height = textField.textHeight;


           return lineMetrics;
      }
 }
```

}

This is the component, but like I said everything is automatically centered.

I've tried paddingLEFT =0; and trying to setStyle("paddingLEFT", 0); but those methods don't work.

```
var test:multiLineLinkButton = new multiLineLinkButton();

        test.label = "sdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfdsfdsdsfdsfdsfdffsdfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfdfdsfdfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdf";
        test.setStyle("textAlign","left");

        var metrics:TextLineMetrics = measureText(test.label);

        trace(metrics.height);
        myCanvas.addChild(test);
```

so metrics.height is giving me a height of 14, which i believe is a single line even though it wraps.

Comment: Lets see the code behind the multiLineLinkButton class, that's going to be how we figure out your height issue.

Comment: Sorry, the first chunk of code above is the  multiLineLinkButton.

Comment: Duh, I should have seen that. So here's what you do. 1)Give your text field a name. 2) write a public function, call it something like getHeight(). 3) have that function return the height of your text field with a getchildbyname. Now you have a function you can call from the main app that will return the height you are looking for.

Comment: So I create a function called getHeight in my custom component file. one isn't "textField" the textfield name? two wouldnt returning textField.measuredHeight give me the height? sorry I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: also textField.textHeight in the component gives an improper height when first run. But when you rollover the links you get the right height... I'm just confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy did it:
http://ooine.com/index.php/2009/10/12/flex-linkbutton-word-wrap/

FYI, this was the first hit on Google for the search term "flex linkButton word wrap"

Comment: Thanks. Which leads me to another question. How do you utilize components in the script tags/ actionscript

Comment: got it var hey:multiLineLinkButton = new multiLineLinkButton();

Thanks

Comment: I tried the code and it works somewhat. For some reason the boundaries of the text are around 50 pixels wide. I increased the .width but all it did was increase the rollover box width and not the actual text.

Comment: var lineMetrics:TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
   lineMetrics.width = 700;
   lineMetrics.height = textField.textHeight;

I just added my own 700 width... 
but now how do I get it aligned to the LEFT, autosize isnt working for me

Comment: alignment is a style, so in mxml it would be `textAlign="left"` in AS it would be `setStyle("textAlign","left");`       Stack overflow tip: in comments you can highlight your code like `this` by using tick marks (the little mark thats next to the [1] key and usualy shares `~`. At least it's that way on U.S. keyboards

Comment: Add a code example to your original question so I can see the code of your custom component. It might be as easy as giving an ID (such as custText) to the text component and building a method that returns custText.height